# wont pass 2000 rpm

Tags: engine, dodge, stratus

I have a 2003 dodge stratus coupe. 2.4L inline 4 cylinder. When I put the pedal to the floor it shoots straight up to 2000 rpm and stop then slowly rises from there. But when I put it in neutral and rev it i can red line it all day its only when its in gear when it does this. The car has next to no acceleration I have to give myself lots and lots of room just to get in with traffic. Its very frustrating please help!

Comment: It sounds like it is in limp mode, CEL on?

Comment: could it be the transmission starting out in top gear